# Other ways of saying mother tongue

Tags: synonyms

I am writing an essay and I need another way of saying "mother tongue" to avoid repetitions. can you help me?

Comment: What have you found already, and why do these options not meet your needs?

Comment: Native language, first language, primary language.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid repetition? In contemporary English prose, arbitrarily using different words for the same entity is generally held to confuse readers and is generally regarded as a literary vice.

Comment: Can you tell us what synonyms you have found in the course of your own research?

Comment: is it correct to say " own language" ?

Answer (score -2):

Synonyms:

- native tongue
- native language
- first language
- natal tongue
- native speech
- parent language
- vernacular

www.thesurus.com

Also, you could consider:

- indigenous language/speech/tongue
- birth language/speech/tongue

Comment: Why down-votes without comments?